# Problems of print java exceptions in one line by logback for docker

Tags: java, logback

I am going to put my java app into docker. But based on our company's logging facility, i have to use `fluentd` to collect containers' log. That requires me to put java stacktraces into one line log.

I did the following, it works in some circumstances but fails in one another.

```java
package com.alex;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void alexExc() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            alexExc();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("oops", t);
        }

        throw new DataFormatException("invalid data format");
    }
}
```

The following is my converter to replace the separator with my specified one "#012"

```java
package com.alex;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThrowableProxyConverter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.IThrowableProxy;
import ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants;

public class OneLineStackTraceConverter extends ThrowableProxyConverter {
    protected String throwableProxyToString(IThrowableProxy tp) {
        String originalStackTrace = super.throwableProxyToString(tp);

        return originalStackTrace.replace(CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR, " #012");
    }
}
```

And then is my logback configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <conversionRule  conversionWord="ex"
            converterClass="com.alex.OneLineStackTraceConverter" />

    <appender name="INFO_FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/logs/loggingmdc/info.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/logs/loggingmdc/info.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %le %logger{0}: ## %msg\n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="DEBUG_FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/logs/loggingmdc/debug.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/logs/loggingmdc/debug.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %le %logger{0}: ## %msg %ex\n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ERROR_FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/logs/loggingmdc/error.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/logs/loggingmdc/error.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %le %logger{0}: ## %msg %ex\n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="THIRD_PARTY_FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/logs/loggingmdc/thirdparty.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/logs/loggingmdc/thirdparty.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %le %logger{0}: ## %msg %ex\n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="THIRD_PARTY_FILE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="com.alex" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR_FILE"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

As you can see in my logback configuration, I add a `conversionRule` to specify that the exception in logging event is to use my `OneLineStackTraceConverter`.

1. it works if I include `%ex` in each pattern for my encoder
2. it does not work if I DONOT include `%ex` in the pattern. why? if the user forgets to include `%ex` in its pattern, do I have some other conversionWord to use for that exception?
3. The last `DataFormatException` does not go to the log file, it comes out in the console, which I also expect it to go to logfile. How can I make it to do so ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> it does not work if I DONOT include %ex in the pattern. why?

Because you declared the conversion word = `ex`. If you don't use it, Logback doesn't know what's on your mind, so it doesn't do anything. Compare this with declaring a variable in the code and not using it, and you should be able to understand.

> The last DataFormatException does not go to the log file

Because it's not logged as far as your code goes. If you throw an exception in your code, Logback (or SLF4J in your case) is not going to automatically catch and log it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the first one, I exactly understand what you explained. But when I use `%ex` in the pattern, the stacktrace is expected formatted into one line. if I delete `%ex` in the pattern, the stacktrace is also in the log file, but they are still the original multiline stackstrace, not using my specified converter.   For the second one, is there some way for me to direct the exception to log file also?

Comment: @Alex 1) Logback matches the log statements with the pattern. If you don't provide a custom parser for your log statements, it'll just dump them to the appender as part of the message. This is analogous to a regex match - only the portions you specify are matched.  2) You can declare a console appender, and use fluentd to pump Docker logs too.